# How to add a value to integer and Update the value in SQLite Database Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm trying to prepare an `android app`.

I have an column in `SQLite Database` with type as `integer`.

For Example the `value` of the `integer` in `Database` is `10`. Now i want to update the `value` of that `integer` to by `adding` another `value` i have say `5`.

So finally i want to `update` the `integer` `value` in `Database` to `15`.

Which is the better solution to `update` the `integer` `value` in `Database` among below options

i) Get the `Integer` `value` from `Database` say `10`, then `add` the `value` i have say `5` and `update` that `integer` `value` in `Database`.

ii) Is there any way to `add` `value` i have say `5` directly to `integer` `value` in `Database` say `10`

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
UPDATE table SET value = value + 5 WHERE id = 1;
```